# How do I hang a heavy brass bar shelving system onto a mirror backsplash?

Tags: hanging, mirror, backsplash, shelf

I have a heavy brass shelf unit I need to screw into a mirror backsplash.  We have tried twice and cracked the mirror both times. The shelf unit consists of brass posts that screw into the mirror at the top and into the counter at the bottom. It has three glass shelves.  It is around 72" long.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Julie

Comment: What cracked the mirror?  Drilling?  Over-tightening the screws?  Its hard to tell what part you need help with.

Comment: Please upload a picture